# Basic Topology: Limit Points

Tags: general-topology

Please see the below and let me know if my logic is not correct for this problem.  Thank you.

> Let $A = (3,4) \cup \{5,6\}$. In the standard topology, prove the following:
>
> (a) There is a point in $A$ that is a limit point of $A$.

The point $3.5$ is a limit point of $A$.  $3.5$ is a member of $(3,4)$ and any open set that contains $3.5$ will include other points in $(3,4)$.

> (b) There is a point not in $A$ that is a limit point of $A$.

The point $3$ is not in $A$ but is a limit point of $A$.  A point is a limit point of $A$ if every open set containing that point contains a point of $A$ that is different from that point.  Any open set that contains $3$ will contain other points in $(3,4)$.

> (c) There is a point in $A$ that is not a limit point of $A$.

The point $5$ is not a limit point.  The open set $(4.5,5.5)$ does not contain any other points of $A$.

Comment: yup, checks out

Comment: Agreed. Looks good.